# How to update the circle degree based on timer increment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html like this :

```
<input id="numberIncrement" type="text" value="2500"/>
<input id="degreeIncrement" type="text" value="0"/>
```

i need to show the countdown 0 to 2500 in 2 second, and based on this, i need to fill the circle degree also 0 to 360

http://jsfiddle.net/ovm6qkvq/2/

so when count down start 0 my degree will be 0

and when it finish to 2500 my degree should be 360.

and it should be done **AT** 2 seocnd, **not IN** 2 second

Comment: You want to google for "linear interpolation" a very basic formula.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to iterate 2500 times in 2000 milliseconds using jquery. This is less than 1 ms per iteration! Depends on too much things.

As for the interpolation, just add this line:

```
 var degreeIncrease = 360/finalNumber;

 // inside loop
 degreeN0 += degreeIncrease;
```

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ovm6qkvq/3/
As you can see, even if you set timer to 1 ms, you won't get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function count(finalNumber,time){

    var intervalTime = time / finalNumber
    var x = 0
    var degreeN0 = 0 ;

    var increaseNumber = setInterval(function() {

       x++
       $("#Text1").val(x);
       degreeNO = (x / finalNumber) * 360;
       $("#degree").val( degreeNO.toFixed(2) );

       if (x == finalNumber) clearInterval(increaseNumber)


   }, intervalTime);


}

count(50,2000)
```

That's how your function would look. When I tested it with 2500 it took 20 seconds. I'd suggest you increase x by a larger number if you're going to display it this way.